# Error when using ActionReducerMap to register reducer: “not assignable to type 'ActionReducerMap<AppState, Action>”

Tags: rxjs, angular8

This is the error I'm getting, I have no idea of what is going on or what to change:

ERROR in src/app/store/app.reducer.ts(12,3): error TS2322: Type '(state: State, action: ShoppingListActions) => State | { editedIngredientIndex: any; editedIngredient: number; ingredients: Ingredient[]; }' is not assignable to type 'ActionReducer'.
      Type 'State | { editedIngredientIndex: any; editedIngredient: number; ingredients: Ingredient[]; }' is not assignable to type 'State'.
        Type '{ editedIngredientIndex: any; editedIngredient: number; ingredients: Ingredient[]; }' is not assignable to type 'State'.
          Types of property 'editedIngredient' are incompatible.
            Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Ingredient'.

shopping-list.actions.ts:

```js
    import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';

    import { Ingredient } from 'src/app/shared/ingredient.model';

    export const ADD_INGREDIENT = 'ADD_INGREDIENT';
    export const ADD_INGREDIENTS = 'ADD_INGREDIENTS';
    export const DELETE_INGREDIENT = 'DELETE_INGREDIENT';
    export const UPDATE_INGREDIENT = 'UPDATE_INGREDIENT';
    export const START_EDIT = 'START_EDIT';
    export const STOP_EDIT = 'STOP_EDIT';

    export class AddIngredient implements Action {
      readonly type = ADD_INGREDIENT;
      constructor( public payload: Ingredient ) {}
    }

    export class AddIngredients implements Action {
      readonly type = ADD_INGREDIENTS;
      constructor( public payload: Ingredient[] ) {}
    }

    export class DeleteIngredient implements Action {
      readonly type = DELETE_INGREDIENT;
      constructor( public payload: number ) {}
    }

    export class UpdateIngredient implements Action {
      readonly type = UPDATE_INGREDIENT;
      constructor( public payload: {index: number, ingredient: Ingredient} ) {}
    }

    export class StartEdit implements Action {
      readonly type = START_EDIT;
      constructor( public payload: number) {}
    }

    export class StopEdit implements Action {
      readonly type = STOP_EDIT;
    }

    export type ShoppingListActions =
    | AddIngredient
    | AddIngredients
    | DeleteIngredient
    | UpdateIngredient
    | StartEdit
    | StopEdit;
```

This is the app.reducer.ts:

```js
    import { ActionReducerMap } from '@ngrx/store';

    import * as fromShoppingList from '../shopping-list/store/shopping-list.reducer';

    export interface AppState {
      shoppingList: fromShoppingList.State;
    }

    export const appReducer: ActionReducerMap<AppState> = {
      shoppingList: fromShoppingList.shoppingListReducer
    };
```

The shopping list reducer:

```js
    import * as ShoppingListActions from './shopping-list.actions';
    import { Ingredient } from '../../shared/ingredient.model';

    export interface State {
      ingredients: Ingredient[];
      editedIngredient: Ingredient;
      editedIngredientIndex: number;
    }

    const initialState: State = {
      ingredients: [
        new Ingredient('Bread', 1),
        new Ingredient('Mayo', 2),
        new Ingredient('Carrots', 1),
        new Ingredient('Apples', 2),
        new Ingredient('Lamb', 5),
      ],
      editedIngredient: null,
      editedIngredientIndex: -1
    };

    export function shoppingListReducer(
      state: State = initialState,
      action: ShoppingListActions.ShoppingListActions
    ) {
      switch (action.type) {
        case ShoppingListActions.ADD_INGREDIENT:
          return {
            ...state,
            ingredients: [...state.ingredients, action.payload]
          };
        case ShoppingListActions.ADD_INGREDIENTS:
          return {
            ...state,
            ingredients: [...state.ingredients, ...action.payload]
          };
        case ShoppingListActions.DELETE_INGREDIENT:
          return {
            ...state,
            ingredients: [...state.ingredients.slice(0, action.payload),
                          ...state.ingredients.slice(action.payload + 1)]
          };
        case ShoppingListActions.UPDATE_INGREDIENT:
         const ingredient = state.ingredients[action.payload.index];
         const updatedIngredient = {
           ...ingredient,
           ...action.payload.ingredient
          };
         const updatedIngredients = [...state.ingredients];
         updatedIngredients[action.payload.index] = updatedIngredient;
         return {
           ...state,
           ingredients: updatedIngredients
        };
        case ShoppingListActions.START_EDIT:
          return {
            ...state,
            editedIngredientIndex: action.payload,
            editedIngredient: { ...state.ingredients[action.payload]}
        };
        case ShoppingListActions.STOP_EDIT:
          return {
            ...state,
            editedIngredientIndex: null,
            editedIngredient: -1
        };
        default:
          return state;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the edit case, I was assigning the index to the ingredient and vice-versa. So I had to change the STOP_EDIT case from this:

```js
    case ShoppingListActions.STOP_EDIT:
          return {
            ...state,
            editedIngredient: -1,
            editedIngredientIndex: null
        };
```

to this:

```js
    case ShoppingListActions.STOP_EDIT:
          return {
            ...state,
            editedIngredient: null,
            editedIngredientIndex: -1
        };
```

I thought I'd better answer this in case someone comes across the same kind of error when learning Angular.

Answer (score 1):

Mr.Eduardo, I think you can also fix this problem by adding the `any` as an additional type to the `ActionReducerMap<AppState>` as below :

app.reduce.ts :

```
 export const appReducer: ActionReducerMap< AppState , any > = {
  shoppingList: fromShoppingList.shoppingListReducer
};re
```

I have also faced the same problem and solved it with this method.